# How to change this color in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, colors, background, settings

In NB 7.2 I have an "index.jsp" file, I've tried "Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors" [Html,Javascript,JSP ...], but I couldn't change this background color, does anyone know how and where to change the bkcolor for "tabs", "tabs-1" as shown in the following image ?

[image]

There are many times I've encountered this kind of situation, I couldn't find where the color setting was, it took forever to get to them, and the sample code may not show all possible color samples, maybe in the next version of NB, someone can come up with this kind of solution : Right mouse-click on any location to display a menu with color setting change option for where the mouse is pointing to ? It detects what file it is [Java,Html,JSP,JS ...] then detect the text it's is pointing to and show color options : fgcolor,bgcolor,highlight color ... This would be VERY USEFUL !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that some settings are taken from XML or HTML or general (= `inherited`).

Take a look at Language ...

- **HTML** --> Parameter Value
- **XML** --> Attribute Value

Or:

- **All Languages** --> String

**Note:** The last one will affect the setting of ***all*** Strings which have the a setting `inherited`.